# Magento 2 not able to override Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems.php file

Tags: magento2, magento2.1.6

I am trying to override this file :-

> **Vendor/Module/Block/Order/Email/Items**

i call this file in my **di.xml** Here is xml code

> **Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems" />
   </config>
```

On following path i have create **DefaultItems.php**

> **Vendor/Module/Block/Order/Email/Items**

Here is code of **DefaultItems.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Order\Email\Items;

use \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo\Item as CreditmemoItem;
use \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Item as InvoiceItem;
use \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item as OrderItem;

/**
 * Sales Order Email items default renderer
 *
 * @author     Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class DefaultItems extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\DefaultItems
{
    public function getAdditionalOptionData()
    {

        return "hello";
    }

}
```

In this file

> **app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/invoice/default.phtml**

I have write following code

```
echo $block->getAdditionalOptionData(); die;
```

Now, when i send invoice email from admin, my code is not working. It should display **hello**.

When i put **di.xml** file code in comment and add function **getAdditionalOptionData** in magento vendor file, **hello** display.

I am using magento 2.1.6

Can anyone please let me know where i make mistake?

Comment: Firstly check whether your module is enabled or not and remove generated and flush cache

Comment: Remove from slash `(\)` at  use \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo\Item as CreditmemoItem;
use \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\Item as InvoiceItem;
use \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item as OrderItem;

Comment: why you need to override the  class

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran I already did that. But not working.

Comment: @AmitBera I want to add additional information in invoice email. When invoice mail sent first time, additional data comes properly. But when i send mail again, at that time additional data not comes. That's why i want to override.

Comment: Did you solve it? I found out that the default.phtml is actually not calling this class. I checked it with get_class($block); and it showed that the block is actually DefaultOrder not DefaultItems.php

Comment: @JohnnyLongneck Yes, i solved. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

After R&D I found solution. I hope this will help to someone.

I have add **default.phtml** file into my module instead of theme So now, new path is

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/email/items/invoice/default.phtml**